# Extract IP addresses from text file without using REGEX

Tags: python, ip-address

I am trying to extract IPv4 addresses from a text file and save them as a list to a new file, however, I can not use regex to parse the file, Instead, I have check the characters individually. Not really sure where to start with that, everything I find seems to have import re as the first line.

So far this is what I have,

```
#Opens and prints wireShark txt file
fileObject = open("wireShark.txt", "r")
data = fileObject.read()
print(data)

#Save IP adresses to new file
with open('wireShark.txt') as fin, open('IPAdressess.txt', 'wt') as fout:
    list(fout.write(line) for line in fin if line.rstrip())


#Opens and prints IPAdressess txt file    
fileObject = open("IPAdressess.txt", "r")
data = fileObject.read()
print(data)

#Close Files
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

So I open the file, and I have created the file that I will put the extracted IP's in, I just don't know ow to pull them without using REGEX.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to step through each character in the text, and every time you find a digit, start trying to build an IP address. If an invalid condition is found, then discard that IP address and then keep scanning. If a valid address is found, then add that to a list of valid addresses. As long as you know what makes an IP valid (In the form x.x.x.x, where X is 0-255), then it should be pretty straightforward to do it that way. There might be more clever ways to do it but that way should work. Does that make sense?

Comment: Tip: you never close `fileObject`. And you don't *have* to close `fin` and `fout` yourself, since the `with` construct handles that automatically. (Also you never use `fout`.)

Comment: As for your question, it would help to see a representative sample of your input file. There might be some indicator preceding or following IP addresses that simplify the process Random Davis suggested. Or if they're delimited from things before and after them with spaces or some other character...

Comment: I'd write a tiny ANTLR grammar if for some obtuse reason someone said I couldn't use regular expression.  Have the grammar recognize IP addresses and discard everything else.

Comment: Why do you not use fout?

Comment: @SKMurph Are you... asking yourself? This is your own post.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Was asking you because you said you never should use it, and I wanted to know why.

Comment: And again, it would help to see a representative sample of the file you're scanning. Can there be multiple IP addresses on one line? When one appears, is it by itself on a line or are there things before and after it? Making a truly *general* solution that can deal with any conceivable variation is almost certainly more work than necessary, but we can't suggest anything more specialized without seeing your file format. (I'm also curious why you can't use regular expressions. It's sort of like asking how to drive in a nail without using a hammer.)

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I wasn't saying you *shouldn't* use `fout`; I just misread your code and thought you currently *weren't*. Using a comprehension like that for its side effects when you don't intend to use the resulting list is an [antipattern](https://treyhunner.com/2019/03/abusing-and-overusing-list-comprehensions-in-python/#Loops_disguised_as_comprehensions), and I didn't read it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.

The function `find_first_digit`, position the index at the next digit in the text if any and return `True`. Else return `False`

The functions `get_dot` and `get_num` read a number/dot and, lets the index at the position just after the number/dot and return the number/dot as `str`. If one of those functions fails to get the number/dot raise an `MissMatch` exception.

In the main loop, find a digit, save the index and then try to get an ip.

If sucess, write it to output file.

If any of the called functions raises a `MissMatch` exception, set the current index to the saved index plus one and start over.

```
class MissMatch(Exception):pass

INPUT_FILE_NAME = 'text'
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'ip_list'
                

def find_first_digit():
    
    while True:
        c = input_file.read(1)
        if not c: # EOF found!
            return False
        elif c.isdigit():
            input_file.seek(input_file.tell() - 1)
            return True


def get_num():

    num = input_file.read(1)  # 1st digit
    if not num.isdigit():
        raise MissMatch
    if num != '0':
        for i in range(2):    # 2nd 3th digits
            c = input_file.read(1)
            if c.isdigit():
                num += c
            else:
                input_file.seek(input_file.tell() - 1)
                break
    return num


def get_dot():
    
    if input_file.read(1) == '.':
        return '.'
    else:
        raise MissMatch


with open(INPUT_FILE_NAME) as input_file, open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as output_file:
    while True:
        ip = ''
        if not find_first_digit():
            break
        saved_position = input_file.tell()
        
        try:
            ip = get_num() + get_dot() \
               + get_num() + get_dot() \
               + get_num() + get_dot() \
               + get_num()
        except MissMatch:
            input_file.seek(saved_position + 1)
        else:
            output_file.write(ip + '\n')
```

Comment: Getting this error, and not seeing where it is coming from,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: sorry, the code was wrong! I already fixed it.